# Show google map in my site with particular location in asp. net

Tags: asp.net, google-maps

I want to show google map in my site with pointing a location in the google maps in asp.net can anybody help me please....steps to get the key and all those stuff....
Thank u

Answer (score 1):

You can use Google maps api in your asp.net page.
You will find helt at http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/291499/Google-Maps-API-V3-for-ASP-NET

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the below sample code.

Its pretty straight forward

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/291499/Google-Maps-API-V3-for-ASP-NET

Answer (score 0):

Here is the specific one you are looking for.

http://www.aspdotnet-suresh.com/2013/01/show-user-current-location-on-google.html

Comment: This is for current location How to set the default location and point it in maps...Thank u for ur reply @jalpesh

Comment: same way you can use the your location and set a location instead of default location via your browser.