# Tutorials for GIS application in Google Map in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, gis

Here what I am trying to implement is GIS (Grographic Information System) Application in Google Map. I googled for the same and I didn't find the appropriate solution. My concern is to implement GIS Application in the my project. I don't figure out how to implement.

Does anyone have any recommendations for tutorials or solutions for implementing GIS Application in asp.net?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First we have to register our Google Map API key so register your own key here and also download the Gmaps.dll from there.
Add the reference to downloaded Gmaps.dll by right-clicking on the solution.

A tutorial using bing is available [here](http://www.asp.net/web-pages/overview/ui,-layouts,-and-themes/displaying-maps-in-an-aspnet-web-pages-site)

More reference Links are [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16931976/show-google-map-in-my-site-with-particular-location-in-asp-net)